# Ruby 1.8.7 vs Ruby enterprise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-enterprise-edition

From what I understand REE is better in terms of garbage collection and much faster when combined with Passenger.

Are there any downfalls of using REE as opposed to Ruby 1.8.7? Random bugs on REE? Compatibility errors? Not advisable for beginners?

This is the only result I found: [Ruby Enterprise Edition vs Ruby 1.9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1402010/ruby-enterprise-edition-vs-ruby-1-9)

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using rvm to develop, you can run your apps unit/functional and acceptance tests against multiple rubies and get an idea how your app will deploy under any interpreter.

- https://rvm.io/set/tests/

Comment: That's a good idea, but I had a horrid time trying to get rvm working on my local version. Have you run your apps against different interpreters and if so any bugs/errors for REE? Thanks for your reply.

Comment: my exp is with jruby and MRI, I haven't used REE much. Again, I would focus on good test coverage to make sure your methods are working as expected on any interpreter. If you tests are solid, you will catch any bugs with REE.